# Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, localhost, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run my applications on Tomcat in Eclipse, but I get *Server Tomcat v8.5 Server at localhost failed to start.* error. 
I have tried everything already. I even purged java on Ubuntu, created a new workspace in Eclipse, new Tomcat server instance. And it was ok when I ran for the first time. But then I`ve made some changes to the code, tried to run it and I get this error again.
I do no think that it is my code problem because I can not run any of my applications on the server when it happens.
I would be very grateful for your help because I am trying to solve this problem for two days already.

I get this output in Eclipse before the window with this error popups:

```
May 20, 2017 7:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8006]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:656)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:355)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:495)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:793)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 11 more
```

And these messages appear after:

```
May 20, 2017 7:22:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
May 20, 2017 7:22:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
May 20, 2017 7:22:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
May 20, 2017 7:22:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8081"]
May 20, 2017 7:22:36 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8010"]
```

Comment: Supposing you know where tomcat is installed, have you checked what the tomcat logs say? They should state what the problem is. Check [tomcat directory]/logs/catalina.out. You could edit your question with the stack trace to help people answer.

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I can`t find such file. I only have files with such names in log folder: "localhost_access_log.date"

Comment: Alternatively, can you post the output that Eclipse displays before the "failed to start" error?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele ok, I edited the question

Comment: I think there will be some `root cause` at the end of the exceptions log.

Comment: @Cassie The root cause is still not displayed. Just a guess: Can you make sure no other instance of Tomcat is running (could be port conflict)? If there is no other running instance, can you try running tomcat outside of Eclipse (Just go to the bin directory and call startup.sh|bat?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele I did it. And Tomcat starts up just fine. Probably, there is some web.xml configurations after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem recently. The conflict was in the pom.xml, because I had both mockito-all and mockito-core dependencies included. You have to check your pom.xml.